# Cannot perform redaction on Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I add a customer regex rule to HDFS configuration via Cloudera Manager:

```
^[1]\d{10}$
```

The instant check shows this rule works fine.

Then I create a hive table (`'create table tmpnum(num bigint);'`) and insert some 11-digit mobile numbers, but related information can still be seen in logs, as shown below:
[image]
[image]
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please add your solution below as an answer.

Comment: That's a comment. You can type below in the *Your Answer* box

Answer (score 1):

To tackle this issue, just removing '^' and '$' which cannot be recognized from your regex expression: [1]\d{10}. A little different from regex in java.